# AWS Tools for PowerShell - Get-EC2Vpc doesn't appear in PowerGUI

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, powergui

I am using first time PowerGUI. I am trying to use the command `Get-EC2Vpc`.

I am using PowerGUI tool. Please see the attached image. For some reason, I can't see the command `Get-EC2Vpc`.

Any suggestion on why?

[PowerGUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFUGM.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely missing the AWS Tools for PowerShell. See this AWS page for help in loading in the AWS Tools: [AWS Tools For PowerShell](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/Index.html)

Comment: I have installed already AWS tools for Powershell. I downloaded it from https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/